# Python, remove characters from database query list, url parse

Tags: python, url, postgresql-9.3

I have big problem and i really don't know what to do with that.
So, my database have 50 rows of movie url. Example:

```
http://www.csfd.cz/hledat/?q=new+girl+s05e03
```

When i execute query from database, I will get list of:

```
['http://www.csfd.cz/hledat/?q=new+girl+s05e03'] ...
```

Point is to grab url from list and give it to function which will get html content(BeautifulSoup)

```
def csfd_content(url):
    content = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    return soup
```

I try it like this :

```
##CSFD BEGIN
cur.execute('Select search_name from movies')
urls = cur.fetchall()
for url in urls:
    search_url = csfd_content(url)
```

Result is:
No connection adapters were found for '['http://www.csfd.cz/hledat/?q=new+girl+s05e03']'
That, clearly mean wrong url! Can somebody help my to get normal url without ['']?

Comment: Just check the type of `url` it may be a list in a list.

Comment: urls = <type 'list'>

Comment: Sorry I meant the type of url in the for loop

Comment: When I try print type(url), result is <class 'psycopg2.extras.DictRow'> ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access rows from a cursor:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Refer to section 11.13.4

> An extract:
>
> class sqlite3.Row
>
> A Row instance serves as a highly optimized row_factory for Connection objects. It tries to mimic a tuple in most of its features.
>
> It supports mapping access by column name and index, iteration, representation, equality testing and len().
>
> If two Row objects have exactly the same columns and their members are equal, they compare equal.
>
> Changed in version 2.6: Added iteration and equality (hashability).

In the question above use:

```
url['name of column in dbase']
```

Comment: :D i feel like a noob. THX very much

Comment: How does this work? By default `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, not a list of dictionaries, so how does `url[column_name]` work?

Comment: Extract from the documentation: 
A Row instance ... supports mapping access by column name and index, iteration, representation, equality testing and len().

Comment: @BenJ: OK. I have removed my down vote, but it would be good if you explained this a bit more in your answer because this is not the default behaviour in psycopg2 nor sqlite3.

Comment: @mhawke I had to double check myself.  Good idea about the extra info the answer

Comment: @BenJ: How is the row factory enabled? How is it done in `psycopg2` which is what the OP is using?

Comment: @mhawke `psycopg2.extras`  provides the referencing interface in DictRow [link]( http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html?highlight=extras#module-psycopg2.extras)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `cursor.fetchall()` returns a *list* of *tuples* (or possibly *lists*), so you are passing a tuple to `requests.get()` when it expects a string. To fix you need to pass the first item in the tuple to `requests.get()`. You can do that with `url[0]`:

```
cur.execute('Select search_name from movies')
urls = cur.fetchall()
for url in urls:
    search_url = csfd_content(url[0])
```